# Use of the "filter" method

Tags: xtend

My intention is to use filter method in an expression within the for loop. Now, the code looks like this:

```
«FOR interf : delegates.getInterf(delegate)»
          «IF !bridgeInterfaces.contains(interf)»
              ...
          «ENDIF»
«ENDFOR»
```

So, the aim is to have something as:

```
«FOR interf : delegates.getInterf(delegate).filter[!bridgeInterfaces.contains]»
```

The above, however, is incorrect. How could I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Please try `«FOR interf : delegates.getInterf(delegate).filter[!bridgeInterfaces.contains(it)]»`. `it` is the name of the lambda parameter if you don't put an explicit name, e.g that would be equivalent to `filter[it | !bridgeInterfaces.contains(it)]`

Comment: bridgeInterfaces is not recognized within filter.

Comment: Where does it come from in your first snippet?